# Why is the value of spin $\pm 1/2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, electrons, lie-algebra

I understand how spin is defined in analogy with orbital angular momentum. But why must electron spin have magnetic quantum numbers $m_s=\pm \frac{1}{2}$? Sure, it has to have *two* values in accordance with the Stern-Gerlach experiment, but why precisely those values?

Comment: There is a definition of the units thing here, and a why does the intrinsic angular momentum have a lower limit than the rotational angular momentum question. Can you say which you care about?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29655/2451

Comment: Albeit it's not good to draw analogy between electron spin and classical rotation, but here it helps to understand nature of electron spin. Imagine earth flips it's rotation direction, so that angular momentum changes as $\vec L \to -\vec L$. That's why electron has spin angular momentum of $+{\frac {\hbar }{2}},-{\frac {\hbar }{2}}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is what OP is really asking(v1), but it is a remarkable fact in [representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation), that it is possible to deduce just from the assumptions that

1. the Hilbert space $V$ of states is $2$-dimensional, and
2. the real $so(3)$ [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) 
   $$[\hat{S}_i, \hat{S}_j ] ~=~i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{S}_k \qquad\qquad (A)$$ 
   of spin operators $\hat{S}_i$ [acts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation) on $V$,

that

$$ {\rm the~eigenvalues}~\hbar m_s~{\rm of~the~spin~operator}~\hat{S}_z\qquad\qquad (B) $$

can *only* be one out of the following two alternatives:

1. $m_s=\pm \frac{1}{2} $. ($V=\underline{2}$ is a dublet representation with spin $s=\frac{1}{2}$.)
2. $m_s=0$.  ($V=\underline{1}\oplus\underline{1}$ is a sum of singlet representations with spin $s=0$.)

Of course, the second alternative is not relevant for electrons, which have spin $s=\frac{1}{2}$.

For a proof using ladder operators, see e.g. section 5 of ['t Hooft's lecture notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg.html). The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).

To summarize the logic, once we have adapted the scaling convention of (A) and (B), there is no ambiguity left in what we *mean* by the variable $m_s$. Once we agree on the *meaning* of $m_s$, we can have a meaningful discussion of the possible *values* of $m_s$. We next use representation theory to conclude that the *values* of $m_s$ are half integers. Similarly, the definition of the spins $s\geq 0$ are not arbitrary, but scaled in such a way that $\hbar^2s(s+1)$ become the eigenvalues for the [Casimir operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_invariant) $\hat{S}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Particles with non-zero mass have spin 1/2 because space is three-dimensional. A spinor has four real components, representing probability density and three functions describing the three (independent) components of momentum. There is a preprint on this on arxiv.

Comment: as it stands now, this is not helpful unless you explain how the 3d space is connected to spin-1/2, or why you could not just have any 2 values (say, 1/3 and 7/5).